# dotnet test and publish tests to TFS 2015

Tags: testing, build, msbuild, tfs-2015

I have executed my tests using the command:

> dotnet test -l trx

But when I saw the my test results are not appearing in the build summary:[image: No test results]

**Some hint show to make it visible? Within TFS2015, and I can't use the current build step for running tests as they do not work with dotnet core apps**

This is the output of the tests in my logs:

```
2017-06-01T14:56:08.3158317Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.0.0

2017-06-01T14:56:08.3158317Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

2017-06-01T14:56:08.4228414Z Starting test execution, please wait...

2017-06-01T14:56:11.4560909Z Results File: D:\APPS\NVSDeploymentAgent\_work\12\s\tests\Tests\TestResults\2017-06-01_16_56_11.trx
```

Comment: Do you have a "publish test results" task configured in your build definition?

Comment: Martin, I added that and actually it worked for trx files. Add it as the answer and I maked it as answered ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the generated `trx` files available as test results in VSTS/TFS, use the "Publish Test Results" task:

[image]